# jQuery/JavaScript to compare maximum and minimum values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery to compare the values of two input fields. One is the "maximum" value and one is the "minimum" value. The objective of the validation is to check if the minimum value is greater than the maximum value.

My logic is almost working but with a small bug. It is triggered with an onBlur event (on one of the tested fields) and once the pop-up alert displays, the user can click anywhere else, and the test is no longer run (thus allowing the minimum value to be greater than the maximum.

Here is the jQuery:

```
//Function to validate if maximum benefit value is more the minimum benefit value
function minMaxValues(){
    var maxAmt = ($('#maxAmount').val());
    var minAmt = ($('#minAmount').val());
    if ((minAmt != '') && (maxAmt != '') && (maxAmt < minAmt)){
        alert('The maximum benefit amount must be larger than the minimum amount.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    } //end maxAmt minAmt comparison
}//end minMaxValues function
```

The HTML:

```
<label>Maximum Benefit Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" name="benefit_max_amount" value="" onBlur="minMaxValues();" id="maxAmount">
<label>Minimum Benefit Amount</label>
    <input type="text" name="benefit_min_amount" value="" onBlur="minMaxValues();" id="minAmount">
```

How do I get jQuery to look at the page **all** the time and compare the values so that the condition can never be true without an alert (warning)?

EDIT:
I should state that I'm looking for something modular, so that it can be used in other locations (thereby allowing this to go into an external js file, and not execute on page load, but only by calling a function.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delegate the check using jQuery on function so that it will check whenever the value changes in the inputs.

```
$('#container').on('change', 'input[name="benefit_max_amount"], input[name="benefit_min_amount"]', function(){
  return minMaxValues();
});
```

- container is the element used for demonstration purpose but you should use the one which contain the input elements on your page.

And your html need not contain any onblur events

```
<label>Maximum Benefit Amount:</label>
<input type="text" name="benefit_max_amount" value="" id="maxAmount">

<label>Minimum Benefit Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="benefit_min_amount" value="" id="minAmount">
```

Your JavaScript function (changed as mentioned in comments to parse integer values)

```
function minMaxValues(){

    var maxAmt = ($('#maxAmount').val());
    var minAmt = ($('#minAmount').val());

    if ((minAmt != '') && (maxAmt != '')){
      try{
        maxAmt = parseInt(maxAmt);
        minAmt = parseInt(minAmt);

        if(maxAmt < minAmt) {
          alert('The maximum benefit amount must be larger than the minimum amount.');
          return false;
        }
      }catch(e){
        return false;
      }
    } //end maxAmt minAmt comparison

    return true;

}//end minMaxValues function
```

Finally the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/x3kYs/3/

Comment: $('body') is too general and will slow down the page. Should use something more local.

Comment: OP does not show and container, so used body, otherwise what you said is correct. Updating it with some container name :)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about using body. I'm looking for something more modular, too, so that it can be used in other locations (thereby allowing this to go into an external js file, and not execute on page load.) -- I'm editing my post to include this information.

Comment: I've attempted to do this, but it is creating more than one alert to pop-up (requiring both to be dismissed before being able to edit the fields.) Any idea why?

Comment: Most probably you have not removed onblur on your input elements. see my edited answer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I fixed that. Now, the problem is that the alert pops up once, but never again (it never prompts the user to fix the mistake again.) This is the same problem I had to begin with. Is there not any way to get jQuery to force a change and not allow the user to continue until it is fixed?

Comment: You should add the check also on your form submit so that user will have to correct it before submitting the form. e.g. `$('form').submit(function(){return minMaxValues();})`

Comment: That is the most logical conclusion. I was thinking this is the only way possible, if the user has not caught on by then. Thank you. :)

Comment: I'm getting random problems. As I rapidly change the fields, I'm getting the error that the min is larger than the max when that condition is false. Something is not working right, here.

Comment: Try parsing the values for integer before comparing. For example `try{var val1 = parseInt(inputValue), var2=parseInt(inputValue2); if(val1 < val2) { // do something} else {//do something}}catch(e){return false;}`

Comment: @Nagarjun wow! you've just gone way beyond my comprehension of JS. I appreciate the effort -- greatly -- but I don't have the first inkling of how to do that! :)

Comment: Full JS function in answer now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to remove joeshmo's code. Here it is again: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3kYs/2/)

Comment: I guess you are new to jQuery. Anyway, see my answer for new fiddle. You need to attach the event to your inputs after loading the dom. Your fiddle does not have any code I mentioned. Also note that change event fires only when value in textbox changes. if that is not you need, use blur event.

Comment: Thank you so very much -- your contribution to this community is **immense**! (Yes, I am very new to jQuery -- thank you for your time and patience.)

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely built upon Nagarjun's answer, but since OP specifically asked for a more reusable solution, consider this...

Change the html thusly:

```
<div id="container">
    <label for="maxAmount">Maximum Benefit Amount:</label>
    <input name="benefit_max_amount" id="maxAmount" data-range="benefit" data-aspect="max">
    <label for="minAmount">Minimum Benefit Amount</label>
    <input name="benefit_min_amount" id="minAmount" data-range="benefit" data-aspect="min">
</div>
```

I've added two `data` attributes to each `input`.  One to group them as a range pair (`data-range`) and one to distinguish which is which (`data-aspect`).

Then you can add this javascript and run it anywhere you like, it will only affect pages with elements like those above:

```
function validate_range() {
    var range = $(this).data("range");
    var min = + $("input[data-range=" + range + "][data-aspect=min]").val();
    var max = + $("input[data-range=" + range + "][data-aspect=max]").val();

    if (min && max && min > max) {
        alert("Invalid Range");
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#container").on("change", "input[data-range]", validate_range);
});
```

To reuse the script, you just need to create two `input`s and give them a matching `data-range` and appropriate `data-aspect`s.  I leave the task of getting a custom alert message through up to the OP.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQ59m/)

Comment: Doesn't the very presence of `$(function () {});` wrapping a function make it non-modular? That code would have to be on-page, otherwise it would run everywhere, whenever the js is included, on page load. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "modular".  You can have multiple `$(document).ready()` calls.  Is that is what you think is non-modular about it?